# Programmatically timeout a test in MSTest

Tags: c#, tfs, mstest

I've got a situation where I'm using a unit test to execute an external tool which performs a test. I can determine from the tool's exit code whether the test passed, failed or timed out.

Is there some way that I can fail the unit test which will set the test outcome to timeout instead of failed?

I've tried throwing a TimeoutException, but this has the same result as using an Assert.

**Edit:**
We're linking the unit tests up with test cases in TFS. In Microsoft Test Center a test in a test run can have many states. One of which is the timeout state. I'm trying to fail my test so that it correctly shows up in this state and does not get bunched up with the failed test cases.

Comment: If your test relies on an external tool to do some work then it's not a unit test. Ideally you'd be mocking out the external tool so you can test *your* code, ragardless of whether *their* code works as expected.

Comment: @Jamie: That is nitpicking. He is probably doing an integration test but (like many other people) calls it a unit test just because it is run in a test runner.

Comment: He could be @erikkallen, however he could also be intending to write this as a unit test but doesn't fully grasp mocking or know that it is even a thing to be done. In the case of the latter my comment might nudge the OP in a useful direction, if not, no harm done.

Comment: @erikkallen is correct, we are running these test as integration/load/... tests.

Comment: I'm calling it a unit test because that is the mechanism by which I'm executing the test.

Answer (score 20):

You can set timeout limit per test, using addition of Timeout(millisecond) in Test attribute...

```
[TestMethod, Timeout(2000)]
```

Test will fail if execution takes longer than 2 seconds.

Thanks
Marko

Answer (score 3):

It is not really "programmatically" but you could:

- [Set Time Limits for Running Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243175%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in Visual Studio
- Use Test Settings in *Microsoft Test Center* if you run your tests from *Microsoft Test Center* or using *tcm.exe* (see [Run Tests from the Command Line Using Tcm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465192))

  [image]

Your test just should wait if it recognized that the external tool returns with the time out exit code (this would be the "programmatic" part.)

So the testing framework will set the test outcome to "Timeout" for you.

Especially if your tests are automated it would be a suitable solution, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

In unit testing you dispose with 2 colors: green and red. There's no *timeout* color.

So I guess you could manually fail the test in case your external tools timeouts:

```
Assert.Fail("External tool used to do this test timed out");
```

The way to detect that your external tools has timed out will of course depend on the external tool you are using and the way you are invoking it from your unit test.

Comment: Have a look at Microsoft Test Center and you'll find more than just Green and Red. If a test takes too long (times out) you also get Yellow.

Comment: I'm tempted to vote this answer down since I think that it was clear from the question (even in it original form) that it is exactly not what I'm asking and that I've already considered using an Assert.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach throwing a `TimeoutException` seems to be a good choice. However the  `TimeoutException` doesn't derive from [UnitTestAssertException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.unittestassertexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You may want to do one of the following things:

1. Throw an [AssertFailedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assertfailedexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) indicating the reason as string.
2. Sub-class the [UnitTestAssertException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.unittestassertexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with a custom `UnitTestTimeOutException` and throw that.
3. Use `Assert.Fail` as @Darin-Dimitrov [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12512554/27083).